# by install the model of python i have error of exit status 2

Tags: python, installation

I'm using 64-bit python 3.4.3 on my 64-bit win 10 computer.
when i am trying to install the model I met this problem at first.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL7PN.png)

so i type this code "SET VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%“(beause I use the Python3 and I've already installed the Visual Studio 2015)
it seems useful but the problem turns into a new one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWORf.png)

Comment: What are you calling 'model' ? By the first image we see that python is working.

Comment: sorry I made a spell mistake. It is "Module" not medel. But it indeeds has a problem.The last line in Pic.1 shows,vcvarsall.bat can't be found.

Comment: what happens if you type `python` in your console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can noly solve this problem by using Python 2.7. After I install the Python 2.7 and C++ Compiler for 2.7 I can finally install the module.